# Restricting Java package access

Tags: import, package, classloader, rule

Ie. I have a GUI package, and a Logic package.

How can I prevent the Logic classes from importing GUI classes? Others(or myself) working on the same project might do that, which I want to prevent.

A solution could for example be a check in JUnit, that fails if its done, or a runtime check that throws an exception. Something along these lines, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write such a test using JDepend or DependencyFinder or [Degraph](https://github.com/schauder/degraph).

Degraph is the only of the three tools that explicitly is intended to actually write tests for cases like this. Also AFAIK JDepend does not find all dependencies in more recent Java Versions (like classes mentioned in Annotations).

I'm the author of Degraph so I'm obivously biased.

Answer (score 0):

I created the  [JabSaw](http://www.jabsaw.org) project. It allows you to define modules by using annotated classes and to express the relationships between the modules. By default, a module contains all classes in a single package.The restrictions can be checked using a Maven plugin, from the command line or from a unit test. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

One solution which comes to my mind is make GUI classes package private. Although you cannot isolate only one package and say, only Logic classes cannot use GUI, but other can.